# Redirecting output of a C program as input of another program in Linux command shell

Tags: c, linux, shell

I wrote a program `p1.c` which takes input from the linux command shell (`Using- char n=argv[1]`). I want the character output of `p1.c` to be taken as input of program `p2.c` . How can I do this? I used the command
`./p2.out  < ./p1.out T > output.txt`. It doesn't seem to work as 'T' is taken as input for `p2.out` and its output is written in `output.txt`.

Comment: `char n=argv[1]` wrong it should be `char* n=argv[1]` Show your code here

Comment: What about `./p1.out T | ./p2.out`?

Comment: @DennisMeng: What about putting answers in answers section instead of comments :) ?

Comment: @0xc0de Yeah, it's a recurring thing actually. Got way too used to questions that needed clarification.

Comment: Just a thought, but if you want the output of p1 to be used as a parameter to p2 then you should look into `xargs`. From `man xargs` "The xargs utility reads space, tab, newline and end-of-file delimited strings from the standard input
     and executes utility with the strings as arguments."

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!...xargs worked! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29): `./p1.out T | ./p2.out`

Comment: its giving a segmentation fault!

Comment: Then it's probably an error in your program. I doubt the Unix pipe has a bug.

Comment: Try running `./p1.out T > output.txt` and then `./p2.out < output.txt` to see which program is faulty.

Comment: how should the output of p1.out be so that it can be taken as input of p2.out?

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix) (the word 'pipeline' in the answer is actually a link).